# What is best approach for pdf generation front end angular or back end Java?

Tags: java, angular, itext, pdf-generation, jspdf

I would like to here few expert advise to make this decision.
We have web app angular as UI and spring boot as back end.
requirement is to generate PDF of dashboard which we are showing on UI contains few data table with client side pagenation and also need to add extra header footer in pdf which we are not showing currently on UI. font requirement is given by client and must follow.
Considering following two options--
1. Itext pdf generation in java where we will design pdf similar to UI dashboard.
2. use some js library like jspdf and write dashboard inner html to pdf.

Need to understand what is pros and cons of each approach,which is good out of both?

Comment: 3. Write the dashboard inner html to pdf using iText + pdfHTML add-on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have client and server side options I suggest it's worth prototyping a typical document in both approaches (if you can spare the time).  The reason is that there are advantages to each and it depends really how specifically you want your PDF to be like your html.

Generally I prefer server-side generation because:

- you have access to data possibly not on the client (eg what is going into your header and footer maybe)
- you can store the document server side (if relevant) then deliver to the client

However you said "font requirement is given by client".  If the client is subject to change and you need that reflected automatically in the paginated PDF, then Amedee's suggestion of html to pdf might be your best option.

I hope that helps.
Paul.